# How can I pass in a row vector using Rcpparmadillo in R?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I'm writing a function using Rcpp for R where I want to perform vector cross products. So in R I am performing

```
t(v)%*%v
```

So I've written the following Rcpp function to do this

```
arma_code <-
    "arma::mat arma_vv(const arma::vec& v1, const arma::vec& v2) {
       return v1.t() * v2;
   };"
arma_vv = cppFunction(code = arma_code, depends = "RcppArmadillo")
```

This works fine, but I'd rather handle the transpose in R as there are situations where v1 has been transposed before input, so I tried the following instead

```
arma_code <-
    "arma::mat arma_vv(const arma::vec& v1, const arma::vec& v2) {
       return v1 * v2;
   };"
arma_vv = cppFunction(code = arma_code, depends = "RcppArmadillo")
```

but it seems to convert v1 to a column vector, even if I pass it through as a row vector, so I get an error

```
Error: matrix multiplication: incompatible matrix dimensions: 1000x1 and 1000x1
```

Comment: There is no data structure "row vector" in R and you are not declaring a "row vector" in Armadillo. I wonder why you think you are passing a row vector. You don't show data or how you call the function. I believe you can just use the first function because an R matrix should be treated as an R vector as input (i.e., the dimension attribute will just be ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few short minutes with the (generally excellent and accessible) [Armadillo documentation](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) would make it clear that for a *conformant* outer product you need a *column vector* (or `arma::colvec`) and a *row vector* (or `arma::rowvec`).

RcppArmadillo supports both, but `arma::vec` is a shorthand for `arma::colvec`.

```
> code <- "arma::mat vp(arma::colvec cv, arma::rowvec rv) { return cv * rv; }"
> Rcpp::cppFunction(code, depends = "RcppArmadillo")
> vp(as.numeric(1:4), as.numeric(1:4))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    4    6    8
[3,]    3    6    9   12
[4,]    4    8   12   16
>
```